# APK no compatible con mis dispositivos Android

Tags: android, google-play

Llevo cuatro actualizaciones de unas de mis apps modificando el `AndroidManifest.xml` para si logro que en la ficha salga "aplicación compatible con todos tus dispositivos" y no tengo éxito [la ficha de la app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.caminsderonda.pro).

Dispongo de los siguientes dispositivos

- EEpad TF101 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
- ACER LIQUID Z200 (KITKAT)
- MOTO G (Lollipop)

**Update**
He bajado una versión SDKmin, eliminado `support-screen` y `android:supportsRtl`

Defino la API para dispositivos API 14+
En todos consigo instarlo mediante `AndroidStudio` pero en la ficha de google play, me sale que no es compatible con ningún dispositivo.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="caminsderonda.wordpress.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.DetailedActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_activity_title" />
        <activity
            android:name="pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/about_title_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Y en el app.graddle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'app.caminsderonda.pro'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 214
        versionName '2.1.4'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
   compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

Dentro de la consola en el apartado compatibilidad del dispositivo

Compatibles:  10685

Tengo check verde a todos mis dispositivos que tengo, pero aún así en la ficha playstore la que ve el usuario, me sale "Esta aplicación no es compatible con ninguno de tus dispositivos" los tengo asociados todos a la misma cuenta.

Seria de agradecer los que dispongáis de un MotoG si podéis visitar la [ficha de la app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.caminsderonda.pro) desde desktop con vuestra cuenta asociada, así poder ver si os muestra si es compatible con vuestro dispositivo

Dejadme un comentario aquí de cómo se os notifica la compatibilidad.

**UPDATE / SOLUCIONADO**

Por fin ya he encontrado porque me informa que mis dispositivos no son compatibles.

Si la app es de pago, como Google no deja que el mismo developer pueda comprarla, aparece ese mensaje.

Mi última prueba ha sido sacar una nueva `app de pago`, y después ponerla `gratis`

**Mientras está de pago:** Esta aplicación no es compatible con ninguno de tus dispositivos.

**Cuando la he puesto GRATIS:** Esta aplicación es compatible con todos tus dispositivos.

Gracias a todos, por las respuestas, he marcado como correcta la que más dispositivos compatibles me ha ofrecido.

Comment: Revisa que los números de los SDK de tus archivos proguard-android.txt y proguard-rules.pro coinciden con los de tu gradle. Esto debería ser automático, pero habiendo venido de Phonegap, quiza estos no se han actualizado correctamente.

Comment: @Webserveis he revisado tu Manifest.xml y hay otro detalle por usar  el permiso ACCESS_WIFI_STATE  te recomiendo agregues, <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" /> ´para que los dispositivos que no tengan Wifi no sean filtrados.Además es necesario para tu aplicación android:installLocation="auto" ? tus dispositivos cuentan con almacenamiento externo?

Comment: @Elenasys el Moto G que tengo si que tiene almacenamiento externo los otros dos "lo soportan" pero no tienen sdcard agregada, si probaré para la próxima actualización de los permisos poner a false, ya que no es un requisito 100%, es una guia offline que las fotos se cargan online

Comment: @Webserveis que sucedio con esto, el problema es que tienes que subirla para ver si es compatible con los dispositivos? El mayor problema que veia es <supports-screens así como android:supportsRtl="true", pero con eso ya puedo soportar tu aplicación en mis dispositivos. ahora con <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" /> te sugiero veas en la consola de desarrollo tu modelo de dispositivo si ya es soportado, sin necesidad de publicar tu application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeramente podemos descartar que es por el  `minSdkVersion`  ya que lo tienes definido como 15  (4.0.3 and up)

pero veo que tienes
`android:supportsRtl="true"` soportado por api 17 en adelante (Android 4.2, 4.2.2)

Si se soporta en todas las densidades y tamaños trata eliminando :

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true">
    </supports-screens>
```

En mi caso, no agrego `supports-screens` ya que es inherente que la aplicación es para cualquier densidad de pantalla.

En el caso de incluir en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` elementos que usen `<uses-feature>`, que sirve para filtrar elementos que no reunen caracteristicas de hardware o software, se pueden marcar como "no requeridos", no los incluí al inicio de mi respuesta ya que no tienes este tipo de elementos en tu manifest.xml, pero lo agrego para documentar esta respuesta.

Por ejemplo si definieras el uso de Bluetooth y Camara en tu aplicación, para ciertos dispositivos que no contaran con estas caracteristicas, serian filtrados y no podrias encontrarlos en la playstore:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

pero puedes definirlos como "no requeridos" para que los dispositivos que no cuenten con estas caracteristicas, puedan usar tu aplicación:

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
 android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
android:required="false"/>
```

para más información;
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

#### Update:

Revisando con más detenimiento tu AndroidManifest.xml y basándonos en la lista de [permisos que implican requerimientos de alguna característica de Hardware](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions)

Para `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` agrega:

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
```

Esto quiere decir que los dispositivos que no soporten **[Wifi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wifi)** no serán filtrados por tu aplicación.

Comment: Probaré de quitar lo de Rtl que lo ha puesto AndroidStudio por mi y lo de las supports-screens, acabo de subir versión a producción, supongo ha de pasar unas cuantas horas para que todo quede actualizado, ya informaré.

Comment: @Webserveis Las aplicaciones Android en las que he participado nunca agregamos <supports-screens, ya que es implicito que deben ser soportadas en todos los dispositivos. La actualización de las apps ocurre en algunas horas como comentas

Comment: Buenas, ya ha pasado un tiempo y aun me sigue mostrandome que no tengo dispositivo compatible, ahora subiré en producción igual que he actualizado la pregunta.

Comment: @Webserveis veo que eliminaste supports-screens y android:supportsRtl , te puedo comentar que anteriormente ninguno de mis dispositivos era compatible con tu aplicación, ahora todos son compatibles. Con cual dispositivo estas teniendo problema para que sea compatible?

Comment: Tengo problemas con mis dispositivos, en todos se carga correctamente con Android Studio, pero si busco mi app con desktop donde tengo la cuenta de google asociada con los devices, me dice que no tengo ninguno compatible (los de la pregunta). No ser si tiene nada que ver que las primeras versiones fueron hechas con Phonegap y después hice el cambio a nativo, con el targetSdk a 23 que con phonegap lo tenia a 21 (no me deja bajarlo)

Comment: Deberias probar en los dispositivos si es verdad que no funciona. Por otro lado la última versión con el más reciente versión code es la que sobreescribe a las anteriores y veo que tienes definido un minSdkVersion=14 que supongo tus dispositivos usan una version mayor por lo tanto no debe ser problema. Veo que tienes  installLocation="auto" es necesario para tu application  instalar en el external storage?

Comment: Porfin he podido averiguar lo que pasa, google debería dar más información de "cosas a tener en cuenta en Googleplay"

Answer (score 1):

Algunos dispositivos no soportan algunas características. Como puede ser una cámara frontal, acceso Wifi u otros. Por esta razón trata siempre de incluir a tus permisos un `requiered=false` a no ser que sea 100% necesario para que te aplicación funcione.

```
<uses-permission 
 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
 android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
 android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
 android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:required="false" />
```

Por otro lado, revisa que los números de los SDK de tus archivos proguard-android.txt y proguard-rules.pro coinciden con los de tu gradle. Esto debería ser automático, pero habiendo venido de Phonegap, quiza estos no se han actualizado correctamente.

Espero que te ayude,

un saludo.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima actualización.

Comment: Cree un proyecto nuevo con AndroidStudio, sin importar nada de phonegap, quiero decir la app en la tienda primeras versiones usaba phonegap, despues renové todo desde 0, java puro y duro.

Comment: Vale, entonces no debería ser por eso, no obstante échale un vistazo con el notepad por si acaso.