# No encuentro mi app recién publicada en el play store desde una tablet

Tags: android

Acabo de publicar mi aplicación en la tienda de google. Todo es correcto a simple vista, puedo encontrarla en el buscador desde cualquier móvil y desde cualquier tableta china. El problema aparece cuando intento buscarla desde mi samsung galaxy tab 9.7, no hay ni rastro de ella.

EDIT:

Añado el Manifest y el gradle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.github.hathibelagal.pn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.github.hathibelagal.pn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.github.hathibelagal.pn" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.clases.RegistrationService"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.clases.TokenRefreshListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.clases.NotificationsListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.clases.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.ComunicadosListado"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.Incidencias"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.MuestroComunicado"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.Catalogos" />
    <activity android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.FotoComunicado" />
    <activity android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.MisIncidencias" />
    <activity android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.MuestroIncidencia" />
    <activity android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.Log" />
    <activity android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.AreaCliente" />
    <activity android:name="com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.actividades.Registrar"></activity>
</application>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.audiobus.oftecnica2.appcorporativa"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"

compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
```

}

Comment: graddle o manifest?

Comment: Desde el android studio, cuando debugeo, va perfecta. Se ejecuta a la perfeccion en la tablet que comento. El problema esta ahora en el play store, que no la consigo encontrar.

Comment: que version de android tienes en la galaxy?

Comment: Si deja instalar, revisa que no se encuentre entre los dispositivos excluidos en play developer console.

Comment: acabo de revisar en excluidos y esta a 0. Lo raro es eso, que desde el studio puedo instalarla sin problemas, pero aqui en la store nada...tiene un android 6.0.1, igual que en mi S6 que si que va...

Comment: Por cierto, la app ocupa unos 4 mb, por lo que dudo que sea un problema de espacio

Comment: Que versión mínima de API soportas, la máxima y tu tableta la versión de Android y sobretodo si es de pago o no la app.

Comment: El permiso <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> es donde creo que hay el problema, una tableta no tiene servicios de llamada.

Comment: madre mia, y entonces las otras tabletas que si me lo detectan?

Comment: Entra en la consola de google play, sección apk y allí encontraras todo el listado de cada dispositivo y los excluidos.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, revisa si tu app es compatible con la versión de S.O que tiene la Tablet.

Intenta colocando la propiedad `<support-screen>` dentro de tu Manifest, solo tendrías que investigar las dimensiones, etc. También agregas la opción `any-density` y le colocas `true` para que tu app acepte cualquier densidad de pantalla, aquí un ejemplo:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Si deseas saber mas información puedes revisar el siguiente [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Comment: lo intentare! y si, la version es compatible! gracias, luego subo la actualizacion a ver que pasa....

Comment: donde pone integer, que deberia poner?

Comment: Esa opción es para colocar un número de anchura mas pequeño de pantalla, eso puedes omitir, recuerda que es un ejemplo, intenta usar las primeras 5 propiedades en true y me comentas.

Comment: Por defecto si no se especifica support-screen, las tiene todas en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

"Probablemente" sea porque **"google play store"** necesita analizar tu app creada,ellos corroboran que no sea ofensivo para los usuarios, debes esperar unos minutos. *Espero que sea de tu ayuda!.*

Answer (score 0):

**Actualización:**

Me temo que el problema está en los permisos, sobretodo en `CALL_PHONE` y `VIBRATE` pocas tabletas tienen esas propiedades, excepto si permite `SIM` etc...

prueba en establecer en algunos de ellos, el atributo `android:required="false"`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.github.hathibelagal.pn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false" />
```

y el `targetSdkVersion` prueba de ponerlo a `23` que equivale a Android versión 6.0

Y la otra dentro de la consola de Google play, en la sección `APK` buscar la lista de Dispositivos no soportados, y busca si está tu tableta o no.

**Otras causas:**

Posibles causas, que me encontrado, a ver si te sirven de ayuda:

- La versión SDK min que está en tu gradle, es superior a tu versión de la Tablet.
- Tienes definida versión SDK max, y tu tableta tiene una versión superior a la establecida.
- Que los permisos que requiere tu app, tu tableta no los soporte.
- Que no tengas capturas subidas para tableta, y tu google play lo tengas configurado solo mostrar apps compatibles en tableta
- Que la app sea de pago, el mismo propietario no la puede instalar y posiblemente "no sea compatible con tu dispositivo", pero si que lo es.

Pero para más detalladamente sube tu gradle y appmanifest.xml

Comment: Pero si el problema es que la app funciona a las mil maravillas en la tablet cuando la cargo desde el android studio. Tengo capturas subidas de smartphone,tablet de 7 y tablet de 10 :(

Comment: manifest y gradle subido!

Comment: Si una cosa es lo que cargas con Android Studio y la otra el filtro de Google en la Google play, que son cosas totalmente diferente. Yo durante medio año una app me salia "no compatible" en la fficha con mis dispositivos, pero con android studio ningun problema

Comment: lo conseguiste solucionar de alguna manera?

Comment: El final si, en el play de dispositivo salia para instalarse, pero como era de pago "el mismo propietario" no la puede comprar, y con el pc me salia "no tienes ningun dispositivo compatible", si la app es gratis, no tengo problemas.

Comment: Aquí hay el hilo donde intentaba todo el proceso. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7608/apk-no-compatible-con-mis-dispositivos-android