# ¿Porqué me aparece que mi app no es compatible con ningún dispositivo? marca ningún dispositivo compatible en Google Play Developer Console

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-console

Acabo de publicar mi primer Aplicación en la play store, pero me indica que ningún dispositivo es compatible con mi APK.

He estado leyendo y la documentación indica que el problema está en el archivo Manifest.xml. Ya he realizado modificaciones pero sigue sin aceptarme dispositivos. Anexo el contenido del archivo Manifest.xml:

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />-->
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />-->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Sensor.accelerometer" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />-->
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />-->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="SafeWay"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Foro_refresh" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Register" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Tips" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Numbers" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".data" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Foro" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Inicio" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Login" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <!--<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>-->
    </activity>
</application>
```

`
[image: Imagen de Play Console]

Answer (score 2):

A simple vista veo que tiene definida esta caracteristica de hardware que deben tener los dispositivos que puedan instalar la aplicación:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Sensor.accelerometer" />
```

Si no es escencial el uso del acelerometro te sugiero agregar la propiedad  `android:required="false"` :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false"/>
```

de otra forma únicamente los dispositivos con acelerometro podrían instalar la aplicación.

Revisa esta respuesta:

[APK no compatible con mis dispositivos Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7608/apk-no-compatible-con-mis-dispositivos-android/7612#7612)

Ahora otro punto importante es revisar la configuración definida en tu `/app/build.gradle` donde defines desde que nivel mínimo o máximo de API soportaría tu aplicación:

```
 minSdkVersion ?
 maxSdkVersion ?
```

revisa:

[Duda sobre APIs y versiones de Android : minSdkVersion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174590/duda-sobre-apis-y-versiones-de-android-minsdkversion)